# handeling querying an item with a single quote in it

Tags: android, sqlite

I get an error anytime I try to query a phrase that has a quote in it, for example `John's day`. How do I handle that?

this is my query

```
Cursor c = db.query(EVENTS_TABLE, new String[] {ID,EVENT,DATE,REAL_START_TIME,REAL_END_TIME}
    ,EVENT + "='" +name+"'",null,null,null,null);
```

name would be `John's day`

Logcat

```
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, event, date, rstime, retime FROM Events_Table WHERE event='Martin Luther King, Jr's Day'
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at com.app.notifyme.CalendarDB.getId(CalendarDB.java:243)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at com.app.notifyme.Calendar.getRow(Calendar.java:378)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at com.app.notifyme.Calendar$3.onItemLongClick(Calendar.java:85)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2580)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2530)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-05 12:25:17.551: E/AndroidRuntime(17085):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: lol your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719499/syntax-error-when-querying-contacts-database-for-an-email my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [http://orafaq.com/faq/](http://orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries):

Use two quotes for every one displayed. Examples:

```
SELECT 'Frank''s Oracle site' AS text FROM DUAL;
```

TEXT:
Franks's Oracle site

Also: [Android quotes within an sql query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296180/android-quotes-within-an-sql-query-string)

Comment: so basically I would have to copy the string, find at what position the quote is in then copy the string to another string while adding another quote?

Comment: well depending on which solution you want, if the '' works you can replace char on the string