# using cursor to get contacts throw sqlite exception

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts, android-cursor

I get the following sqlite exception while querying for contact phone:

```
05-05 04:25:47.276: E/AndroidRuntime(7369): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error: , while compiling:
 SELECT data1, data2 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND ( DISPLAY_NAME = 'Seller's Permit Rose Agent')
05-05 04:25:47.276: E/AndroidRuntime(7369):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
05-05 04:25:47.276: E/AndroidRuntime(7369):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
05-05 04:25:47.276: E/AndroidRuntime(7369):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
05-05 04:25:47.276: E/AndroidRuntime(7369):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
05-05 04:25:47.276: E/AndroidRuntime(7369):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245)
```

I don't know anything about sqlite, as I am not even using it directly. I am using a cursor. The root of the exception is the line:

```
phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE },
                " DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
```

The complete method is

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
    ArrayList<Contact> data = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    contactCursor = contentResolver.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, BaseColumns._ID }, null, null, null);
    if (contactCursor != null) {
      String name = null;
      String phoneString = null;
      long phoneNumber = -1;
      long id;
      InputStream image = null;
      while (contactCursor.moveToNext()) {
        name = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        image = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver, ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            contactCursor.getLong(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID))));
        id = contactCursor.getLong(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

        phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE },
            " DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
```

Comment: escape the single quote in your `name` variable

Comment: @SagarWaghmare If you mean `" DISPLAY_NAME = \'" + name + "\'"` it still crashes with the exception.

Comment: no. use `phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE },
            " DISPLAY_NAME = ?", new String[] {name}, null);`

Comment: @SagarWaghmare do you mind reposting as a response so I may accept your answer: since you were the first person to respond.

Comment: I have reposted it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ideally do,

```
phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE }, " DISPLAY_NAME = ?", new String[] {name}, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error: , while compiling:
>    SELECT data1, data2 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND ( DISPLAY_NAME = 'Seller's Permit Rose Agent')

Exception occured because of the single quote in your display name

Try this

```
name=name.replace("'","''");
```

And then

```
 phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE },
            " DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its due to the single quote in the `name` String. one way is to get rid of the single quote but that's not the right way. If you want that the code should work even with single and double quotes in it, try using rawQuery() instead of using .query() method. See the above 2 threads: [Android quotes within an sql query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296180/android-quotes-within-an-sql-query-string) and [handeling querying an item with a single quote in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746969/handeling-querying-an-item-with-a-single-quote-in-it) . They deal with the same issue.

Comment: Glad to help. Hope it helped solving your issue.